# Why does Crystal Reports throw a LoadSaveReportException in IIS7 but works in Cassini / desktop application?

Tags: iis, iis-7, crystal-reports

I have a method that loads a Crystal Reports file, sets the appropriate login information, and then generates a PDF.

```
ReportDocument rep = new ReportDocument();
rep.Load(...);

// Set table LogOnInfo

rep.ExportToStream(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);

// Save the PDF to disk or return it as web request
```

This exact code works in both

1. A stand-alone WPF desktop application
2. An ASP.NET MVC website running through Cassini launched from VS

but does not work when the same website is deployed to IIS7. It gives a rather unhelpful message and stacktrace.

> An error has occurred while attempting to load the Crystal Reports runtime.
>
> Either the Crystal Reports registry
>   key permissions are insufficient or
>   the Crystal Reports runtime is not
>   installed correctly.
>
> Please install the appropriate Crystal
>   Reports redistributable
>   (CRRedist*.msi) that contains the
>   version of the Crystal Reports runtime
>   (x86, x64, or Itanium)  that is
>   required.  Please go to
>   http://www.businessobjects.com/support
>   for more information.
>
> Exception Details: CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.LoadSaveReportException: An error has occurred while attempting to load the Crystal Reports runtime.

Note that I am using CR 2008 SP2 and the files haven't been named `CRRedist...` since 10.5 so someone has been forgetting to update the messages somewhere :) [Here is a list of all the CR runtimes.](http://wiki.sdn.sap.com/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=56787567)

So why would running the same code referencing the same assemblies work in the two situations listed above but not in a deployed website?

I found [this suggestion](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/aspnet/11/10107771/cannot-export-crystal-rep.aspx) to give the IIS user write access to the temp folder, and it does appear that the Crystal runtime does some work there but I still get the same error even after giving `IIS_IUSR` or `IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool` full access to `%TEMP%`.

I have also tried changing the app pool to use my account as the identity and still receive the same error message so I'm not convinced it's a permissions issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that for any newer versions of Crystal Reports after 10.5 (the one that is bundled with VS2008) there are no 64-bit runtimes.

The "simple" solution is to make the app pool 32-bit and then everything works ok.

There are more explanations found [here](http://forums.sdn.sap.com/thread.jspa?threadID=1398941&start=15&tstart=0) (along with the expected angry responses)

Comment: I know that this is a couple of years later, but I'm now struggling with this issue, trying to get a ASP.NET 2.0 app that runs fine on a Windows 2003 R2 server (64-bit) to now run on a Windows 2008 R2 server.  What I'd like to know is how to make make the app pool 32-bit?

Comment: @Rod For IIS 6 try 'cscript.exe adsutil.vbs set W3SVC/AppPools/Enable32BitAppOnWin64 “true”' or 'cscript %SystemDrive%\inetpub\AdminScripts\adsutil.vbs set w3svc/AppPools/Enable32bitAppOnWin64 1'

Answer (score 0):

You have to install CR version 13, download the msm and build an installer with VSS. Finalley execute the installer (you build) on your server.

Good luck!